# How to make an external requirement internal

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm using version 8.0.858 of Enterprise Architect and I am hoping someone knows how to make an external requirement internal again.

I have searched thru the EA user guide, and this tells me how to make an internal requirement external, but is silent on how to reverse the process.

I have hundreds of requirements linked to Use Cases where the requirement is marked as external, but they shouldn't be as they each only relate to one Use Case.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about
[image]

This makes it difficult to get an overview of what the Use Case requires because when you click on an external requirement, the description does not show up in the textbox, and you have to double-click it to open in a separate window.

My only thought is to hack the database in Access, but I'd rather not if there is any UI functionality. That said, if you have know how to edit the database directly to achieve my goal, then that would be a valid solution too.

Comment: Probably not possible, because external rqmts have element properties of their own (last update, phase, status, ...), so you'd lose them or have to merge them with the use case's element properties when making them internal again.

Comment: Losing that information wouldn't bother me. I really just need the descriptive text.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge this isn't possible, for the reason @observer notes. External requirements are model elements in their own right and thus have far more information associated with them than internal requirements do.

External requirements (and other model elements) are stored in the t_objects table, while internal requirements are in t_objectrequires. Connectors are in t_connector.

I'd advise against trying to hack the database directly. Use the automation interface instead (it can be accessed from an in-EA script); look at the Element and ElementRequirement classes.